# ReactJS Webpack bundle.js syntax error for 'class'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, syntax, webpack

The following code is generated in bundle.js.
Internet Explorer states there's a syntax error for `class` and that is correct.
Why is this in my bundle.js and how can I fix this?

```
let Screen = __webpack_require__.i(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_mobx_react__["observer"])
    (_class = class Screen extends __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react__["Component"] {
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.componentWillRender) {
        this.componentWillRender(this.props);
        }
    }
}) || _class;
```

> SCRIPT0001: Syntax error
>   bundle.js (12470,99)

Comment: Seems you are not transpiling your JavaScript code from ES6 to ES5

Comment: @LucaFabbri I am. It seems like it is just skipping that one keyword. Very weird.

Comment: Please show your webpack config and babel config so we can help

Comment: https://pastebin.com/tqzZWvAu